# Sort with functor error

Tags: c++, sorting, functor

Wondering whether someone can help me with this. The code below is giving me this error:
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

```
template <class T>
class CompareList
{
public:

    CompareList( const long& lBlobFeature, const bool& bIsAscending )
{
    ...
}


bool operator()( T &lhs, T &rhs ) 
{

    double dFirstValue  = lhs.GetValue( ... );
    double dSecondValue = rhs.GetValue( ... );


    if( m_bIsAscending )   // Sort Ascending.
    {
        if( dFirstValue < dSecondValue )
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
    else                   // Sort Descending.
    {
        if( dFirstValue > dSecondValue )
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}

};


CVParentList     *m_pList;
m_pList = new CVChildList[ nBlobs ]; //CVChildList is a derived class of CVParentList

std::sort( m_pList, m_pList+GetBlobsNumber(), CompareList <CVChildList> ( lBlobFeature, TRUE) );
```

**Edit:**
I'm really sorry, actually this is the first error:
error C2664: 'bool CompareList ::operator ()(T &,T &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CVParentList' to 'CVChildList &'

"fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation"
came after and I only saw the last error message. So sorry.

Comment: `bool operator()( T const &lhs, T const &rhs )`

Comment: the error C1903 means the compiler found too many errors to continue. Can you post the whole build log to see where the actuals errors are ?

Comment: The first error, not the last, is usually the interesting one.

Comment: Are you trying to define a comparator for using std::sort<>, std::map<>, etc?

Comment: It seems the real error is:
error C2664: 'bool CompareList <T>::operator ()(T &,T &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CVParentList' to 'CVChildList &'

Comment: It seems that the parent pointer is pointing to an array of child objects and that is probably causing the problem as the the sort function is expecting parent class type objects.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yeah I'm trying to define a comparator for std::sort.
CompareList is a functor.

Comment: Ok.if the inheritance chain is setup as you show here, you don't need a template-comparator. secondly, the template for std::sort<> expects iterators, which are nothing more than glorified type-hardened pointers in your case, and should be fine. I'm looking at your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator, or your dynamic list. need to change. You can throw out the template portion of the comparator and simply declare it as a CVParentList comparator:

```
class CompareList
{
public:
    CompareList(long lBlobFeature, bool isAscending);

    bool operator()(const CVParentList& left, const CVParentList& right) const
    {
        bool ans = false;
        // your comparison code goes here
        return ans;
    }
private:
    bool m_bIsAscending;
};
```

and invoke your std::sort<> as you are doing *without* the template argument

```
std::sort( m_pList, m_pList+GetBlobsNumber(), CompareList( lBlobFeature, TRUE) );
```

You can also allocate the list, sort it, then downcast the list head when you're done:

```
CVParentList *m_pList = new CVChildList[ nBlobs ];
std::sort( (CVChildList *)m_pList, (CVChildList *)m_pList+GetBlobsNumber(), CompareList<CVChildList> ( lBlobFeature, TRUE) );
```

But I really recommend the first option in your case.

Comment: I need the template because I need to reuse the functor class actually. So, the 2nd option worked. Thank you! 
So silly of me when all I need to do is to downcast the pointer! :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need to pass `const` references to your functor, since a comparison should not change the objects being compared. Compilers may or may not require this. Change the functor signature to

```
bool operator()(const  T& lhs, const T& rhs );
```